# Power of the test

Tags: paired-data

How can I calculate the power of paired t-test if the null hypothesis mean is equal to 0. With a standard deviation 0.0373, sample size n=12 and alpha 0.05.?

Comment: Cohen (1988) Statistical power analysis for the behavioral sciences (2nd ed.).  Hillsdale,NJ: Lawrence Erlbaum is a classical reference. You might also consider the pwr package if you are familiar with R.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to any good statistical package (such as R or SAS) there are prepackaged tools for doing this (the `pwr` package in R and `PROC POWER` in SAS). There are probably similar tools in other statistical packages.

Otherwise, you can look into the book by Cohen that @Utobi referred to in a comment.